# Denseness of rationals and continuous maps

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Suppose $f, g : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are continuous and $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}$. Then $f(x)=g(x)$ $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$.

My proof:
Consider the function $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$, clearly it is continuous. Suppose there exists $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(x) \neq 0$. Then either $h(x)>0$ or $h(x)<0$. If $h(x)>0$ then by the denseness of the rationals in the reals, there exists rational $y$ such that $h(x)>y>0$. By the intermediate value theorem, there exists $a\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(a)=y$. But $y$ is non-zero,  a contradiction. Similarly for $h(x)<0$ .
Is the proof correct?

Edit: The proof I wrote is incorrect. A correct proof would be to note that if $x\in \mathbb{R}$ then take any convergent sequence of rationals that converge to $x$ then due to continuity, the $0$ sequence converges converges to $f(x)$ and so due to the uniqueness of the limit, $0= f(x)$ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You have reached no contradiction at all. There is no reason for you to say that there is no $a\in\mathbb R$ such that $h(a)=y$. Yes, no $a\in\mathbb Q$ exists such that $h(a)=y$, but, in principle, there might be an irrational $a$ that would work.

Comment: My apologies for deleting my question, it won't happen again. I really appreciate your answers. May you look at my edit, please?

Comment: It is correct, except that when you wrote $f$ you meant $h$.